# Location for Symfony bundle templates

Tags: symfony

The [directory structure for bundles](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/best_practices.html#directory-structure) specifies that views should be stored in `<your-bundle>/Resources/views`. But then the [best practices for template locations](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/templates.html#template-locations) says that, actually, I should store them in `app/Resources/views`. I can see the conveniences of doing the latter, but I don't understand:

1. If I am organizing things into bundles, aren't I reducing the bundles' portability by "de-bundling" the views?
2. The examples show that `index.html.twig` is easier to write than `AcmeDemoBundle::index.html.twig`, but what if I also have `FooBundle::index.html.twig`? I still need a way to specify which `index.html.twig` I want, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation is correct. Store **reusable bundle's** templates in `<your-bundle>/Resources/views` and your **project's** templates in `app/Resources/views`. There is no conflict.

If you decide to create a bundle make sure it can be reused (that's the main purpose of the bundle). Otherwise keep using your AppBundle. AppBundle will not have two `/index.html.twig`'s.